# Dynamic partitioning in Hive

Tags: mapreduce, hive

I am new to hive.
My input file is of the form
(ID, Date(YYYY-MM-DD), hour(HH), key, value).Table is partitioned on (date, hour)
the input file contains data for seven days(24 hours for each day). When i load this data into hive table, i need the data to be loaded in respective partitions of the table.
Can some please help me out.

Thanks,
Sudhakar.

Comment: Have you tried a Map/Reduce job?

Answer (score 4):

one way is to first load the data into an unpartitioned table (e.g. tmp_some_table in the example below). Then you can do something like:

```
  set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
  set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
  from tmp_some_table tt
  insert overwrite table some_table partition(day, hour)
  select
    id,
    key,
    value, 
    day,
    hour
```

the partitions need to be the last columns in your select clause. The above works on hive 0.7.1. See [the wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/dynamicpartitions.html) for more info. Note that if you have [too many partitions you'll get errors](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=322898).